# Laravel Project with Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I follow this tutorial:

- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/dockerizing-laravel-with-nginx-mysql-and-docker-compose/

When I run the command "docker-compose up -d" and open in the browser I get this error message "Unable to connect".
I think the problem is with configurations off nginx (laravel.conf)
I try apply some tests only to HTTP and i can't put it work.
Thanks in advance

[DockerFile]

```
# Set master image
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install Additional dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    build-base shadow vim curl \
    php7 \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-common \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-mysqli \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-xml \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-json \
    php7-phar \
    php7-zip \
    php7-gd \
    php7-dom \
    php7-session \
    php7-zlib

# Add and Enable PHP-PDO Extenstions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

# Install PHP Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Remove Cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Add UID '1000' to www-data
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

# Change current user to www
USER www-data

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

[docker-compose]

```
version: '3'
services:

  #Laravel App
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: hakase-labs/laravel
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - mynet

  #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
      - "8082:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
      - ./nginx/logs/:/var/log/nginx/
    networks:
      - mynet

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laraveldb
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravelpassworddb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpasswordmysql
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql/
    networks:
      - mynet

#Docker Networks
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name laravel.hakase-labs.io;

    return 301 https://laravel.hakase-labs.io$request_uri;
}

[laravel.conf]

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name laravel.hakase-labs.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;

    # Log files for Debug
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # Laravel web root directory
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    # Nginx Pass requests to PHP-FPM
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well My reputation is less than 50 , I can't comment. I was asking that do you add your ssl to path it specify ?

```
sudo cp /path/to/ssl/fullchain.pem nginx/ssl/

sudo cp /path/to/ssl/privkey.pem nginx/ssl/
```

Do you copy and Paste as it is ? Or you have add the path of your ssl ?

Comment: I generate with openSSL the certificates. This two lines are incorrect. Let me edit the initial post